# Show USB HDD disk % usage on i2c OLED

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have set up a Adafruit 128 x 32 i2c OLED display to show: hostname, IP address, CPU, Memory usage and disk usage for my backup server. The drive is mounted and accessible at `/home/pi/backup`

[image]

I would like show the disk usage % of a USB external 4TB HDD drive instead of the SD card. I've tried to change the filter to a location where I have mounted the drive but no success.

Currently I'm using:

```
            CPU = "{:3.0f}".format(psutil.cpu_percent())
            svmem = psutil.virtual_memory()
            MemUsage = "{:2.0f}".format(svmem.percent)
            cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}\''
            Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
```

This just shows the disk space of the SSD.

I tried: `cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/home/pi/backup"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}\''` unsuccessfully.

This is my first time writing / editing any code.

Thanks.

**Additional information:**

Thanks @Seamus . Output of `df -h`

```
pi@BackupPi:~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3.4G  1.5G  1.8G  46% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  8.5M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   46M  207M  18% /boot
/dev/sda1       3.6T   89M  3.4T   1% /home/pi/backup
tmpfs           383M     0  383M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Output of `lsblk --fs`

```
pi@BackupPi:~ $ lsblk --fs
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1      ext4          bd5bb99c-326a-4116-b6ac-d47b5414f539    3.4T     0% /home/pi/backup
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot   DC3E-E470                             206.9M    18% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs a7adb26a-8b87-4729-99c8-9f5ac069d51e    1.8G    43% /
```

When I try your example I get an error:

```
pi@BackupPi:~ $ df -h | awk '/home/pi/backup/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$4,$5}'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
```

I noticed that I don't have my disks at `/mnt` like you do. Maybe that's the issue? [I followed this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffx4HhNLqfI&t=218s) which had me mount it at `/home/pi/backup`

Also, here is the section that draws the text:

```
draw.text((x, top),       "NAME: " + HOSTNAME.decode('UTF-8'), font=font, fill=255)
            draw.text((x, top+8),    "IP  : " + IP.decode('UTF-8'),  font=font, fill=255)
            draw.text((x, top+16),    "CPU : " + CPU + "% | MEM: " + MemUsage + "%", font=font, fill=255)
            draw.text((x, top+25),    Disk, font=font, fill=255)
```

Thanks for the help.

**Additional Info #2**

So I found that both these commands output the info I'm hoping for but only when entering them into the command line:

```
pi@BackupPi:~ $ df -h | awk '$NF=="/home/pi/backup"{printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$2,$5}'
Disk: 89M / 3.6T 1%
pi@BackupPi:~ $ df -h | awk '/sda1/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$4,$5}'
Disk: 89M / 3.4T 1%
```

But I'm not sure how to format them to add them in the script. I see that some backslashes and apostrophes are used in the Adafruit example but not used when I enter them into bash.

So using this in the script: `cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/home/pi/backup"{printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$2,$5}\''` When I run it with command `python3 infoscreen.py` it crashes and gives me this error:

```
pi@BackupPi:~ $ python3 infoscreen.py
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "Disk: %s / ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infoscreen.py", line 148, in <module>
    DISK = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'df -h | awk '$NF=="/home/pi/backup"{printf "Disk: %s / %s %s
", $3,$2,$5}'' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

If I use `'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/"{printf "Disk: %d/%d GB  %s", $3,$2,$5}\''` It works fine but gives me SD card info only.

Thanks again @Seamus

Comment: It would help help if you would show us what `df -h` looks like in your question. You should also take a look at the output of `lsblk --fs` as it may be easier to parse.

Comment: if the external drive is mounted on `/home/pi/backup` then your code should work - perhaps you did something other than what you say you did

Comment: Instead of `/home/pi/backup/` as the pattern, just use `/backup/` - or - `/sda1/`.  `awk` is *picky* about syntax. IOW, try this: `df -h | awk '/sda1/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$4,$5}' `. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: With respect to: `the section that draws the text: ...` - I'm afraid I cannot help you with that - it looks like it's device-dependent code of some type. But if you were feeding in a text string before, the `awk` output still provides a text string to feed it.

Comment: Added more above under **Additional Info #2**

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Needed an extra \ in front of the `\n`. I found [some info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779365/using-awk-in-popen-gives-runaway-string-constant-error)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Now you have a decision to make: if this answer solved your problem, please [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) & make a decision. If you don't like these answers, then please make your own answer & select that. Otherwise, your question becomes a "zombie" & is recirculated for answers ad nauseum.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               29G  4.5G   24G  16% /
devtmpfs               805M     0  805M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  934M     0  934M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  934M   26M  909M   3% /run
tmpfs                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  934M     0  934M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              1.8T  199G  1.6T  12% /mnt/Passport2TB
/dev/mmcblk0p1         256M   47M  209M  19% /boot
//NetgearNAS-3/backup   11T  1.9T  9.0T  18% /mnt/NetgearNAS-3/backup
tmpfs                  187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1000
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ df -h | awk '/Passport2TB/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$4,$5}'
Disk: 199G / 1.6T 12%

# Or, if you prefer: 

pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ df -h | awk '/Passport2TB/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$2,$5}'
Disk: 199G / 1.8T 12%
```

With the benefit of the `df -h` output from your system, this should work [*verbatim*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbatim) at your command line prompt:

```bsh
df -h | awk '/sda1/ {printf "Disk: %s / %s %s\n", $3,$4,$5}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Seamus . I added additional information above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Adafruit i2C OLED to display correctly using this:

```
            cmd = 'df -h | awk \'$NF=="/home/pi/backup"{printf "DISK: %s / %s %s\\n", $3,$2,$5}\''
            Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
```

It turns out I needed to add another `\` in front of the `n` for this `awk` command to work properly.

@Seamus I'm not able to upvote your comment or select your answer because of my reputation but I appreciate your guidance.